# How do i pass data to mvc controller when using a modal template and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Im using telerik's Kendo UI for MVC and im trying to pass data from js to a controller.

What i want to achieve is to have a modal popup asking to confirm deletion of an object (rather than navigating to a new page).

I manage to get the popup working using demo code so its literally copy paste at this point and can be found here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command

However, i am having an issue passing the ID to the controller.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div id="details-container">
        <h2> </h2>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h2>
                Are you sure you want to delete <code>#= PropertyName #</code>?
            </h2>
            <hr />

                                     //// What do i pass here?!?!     VVVV
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Properties", new { id = ????}))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-actions no-color text-center">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Properties", "Home", null, new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-default" })
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

E:

i just learned that the `#= PropertyName #` syntax is specific to kendoUI, and that i can also use the jQuery syntax `${PropertyName}`

Comment: Just `new { id = Model.ID }` assuming your model contains a property named `ID` (although its will be automatically added anyway if the GET method that generated the view has a parameter named ID)

Answer (score 0):

A hidden field for whatever data you want to send, with a name that matches the controller action method's parameter name, should suffice:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Test(string propertyName){ //... }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Properties", new { id = ????}))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.Hidden("propertyName", "Value to send goes here")
                <div class="form-actions no-color text-center">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Properties", "Home", null, new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-default" })
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
            }
```

It doesn't need to be a string, but that is the simplest example to show as everything has to be parsed out of a string by the Default Model Binder anyway.

Comment: i just learned that the `#= PropertyName #` syntax is specific to kendoUI, and that i can also use the jQuery syntax `${"PropertyName"}`. I am unable to pass either syntax to the `Html.Hidden` method